# C++ continuous read file

Tags: c++, file-io

I've a producer/consumer set-up: Our client is giving us data that our server processes, and our client is giving data to our server by constantly writing to a file. Our server uses inotify to look for any file modifications, and processes the new data.

Problem: The file reader in the server has a buffer of size 4096. I've a unit test that simulates the above situation. The test constantly writes to an open file, which the file reader constantly tries to read an process. But, I noticed that after the first record is read, which is much smaller than 4096, an error flag is set in the ifstream object. This means that any new data arriving is not being processed. A simple workaround seems to be to call ifstream::clear after every read, and this does solve the issue. But, what is going on? Is this the right solution?

Comment: hmm, error? I would simply guess eof with my limited knowledge. in which case clearing the object simply resets the eof status

Comment: AK is right, EOF is set on file open, but your problem is bigger than this.  You have a dinning philosopher issue, you can not read an right to a file without closing it between reads and writes.  Instead of using an actual file you should use an fstream.

Comment: Thank You David and AK!. David, Could you please elaborate a little bit more on " using an actual file you should use an fstream". This is the thing: The client has the system set up to keep the file open for an entire hour, when real-time data is added to the file, which our server is expected to read and process. To be clear there are two fstream objects here -- ofstream by the client writing to the file and ifstream by our server process reading new data using inotify.

Comment: if the server is picking the data read-only, the writer should be able to simply flush after the write, making the close unnecessary.  but does your file grow endlessly?  if not, how does the server know to read from the beginning again?

Comment: Hello Mark, No, the file does not grow endlessly. So, our server application monitors a directory using inotify for new files, and only one file is processed at any point. Each of the new files arriving in this directory is closed at the end of the hour and a new file will be opened for the real-time data for the next hour. For the new file, the fstream object is reset to the new file, which automatically makes it start from the beginning for the new file. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Solved it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52052013/7918560

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, depending on your system it may or may not be possible to read a file another process writes to: On Windows the normal settings when opening a file make the access exclusive. I don't know enough about Window to tell whether there are other settings. On POSIX system a file with suitable permissions can be opened for reading and writing by different processes. From the sounds of it you are using Linux, i.e., something following the POSIX specification.

The approach to polling a file upon change isn't entirely ideal, though: As you noticed, you get an "error" every time you reach the end of the current file. Actually, reaching the end of a file isn't really an error but trying to decode something beyond end of file is an error. Also, reading beyond the end of file will still set `std::ios_base::eofbit` and, thus, the stream won't be `good()`. If you insist on using this approach there isn't much choice than reading up to the end of the file and dealing with the incomplete read somehow.

If you have control over creating the file, however, you can do a simple trick: Instead of having the file be a normal file, you can create it is `mkfifo` to create a *named pipe* using the file name the writing program will write to: When opening a file on a POSIX system it doesn't create a new file if there is already one but uses the existing file. Well, file or whatever else is addressed by the file name (in addition to files and named pipe you may see directories, character or block special devices, and possibly others).

Named pipes are curious beasts intended to have two processes communicate with each other: What is written to one end by one process is readable at the other end by another process! The named pipe itself doesn't have any content, i.e., if you need both the content of the file and the communication with another process you might need to replicate the content somewhere. Opening a named pipe for reading which will block whenever it has reached the current end of the file, i.e., initially the read would block until there is a writer. Similarly writes to the named pipe will block until there is a reader. Once there two processes communicating the respective other end will receive an error when reading or writing the named pipe after the other process has exited.

Comment: Hello Dietmar, Thanks for the elaborate response. Yes, I'm using Linux. I do not have much control over how the input file is created, but I know that we have read permissions. So, this is the task flow. Inotify tells you what the file event was -- created, modified, closed. For each of these events, our server processes any new data -- uses gcount() to check whether new any data was read. After every read, checks eof() and clears the flag if so. For a close event, it would try one last time to process any new data and will close connection to that file.

Comment: Do you have write permission in the directory where the file is located? You only need the access once to create the named pipe. I understand how `inotify()` works but I think it is the wrong tool for the task at hand. Even whe not using a named pipe there may be a way to open a file to block on reads past the end of the file...

Comment: Thanks Dietmar. I agree with you, and shall try to run this by the team!

Answer (score 1):

If you are good with opening and closing file again and again,
The right solution to this problem would be to store the last read pos and start from there once file is updated:

Exact algo will be :

1. set start_pos = 0 , end pos =0
2. update end_pos = infile.tellg(),
3. move get pointer to start_pos (use seekg()) and read the block (end_pos - start_pos).
4. update start_pos = end_pos and then close the file.
5. sleep for some time and open file again.
6. if file stream is still not good , close the file and jump to step 5.
7. if file stream is good, Jump to step 1.

All c++ reference is present at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/
you can literally utilize the sample code given here.

Exact code will be:

```
`
#include <iostream>     
#include <fstream>      

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Please pass filename with full path \n";
        return -1;
    }

    int end_pos = 0, start_pos = 0;
    long length;
    char* buffer;
    char *filePath = argv[1];
    std::ifstream is(filePath, std::ifstream::binary);  

    while (1)
    {
        if (is) {

            is.seekg(0, is.end);
            end_pos = is.tellg(); //always update end pointer to end of the file  
            is.seekg(start_pos, is.beg); // move read pointer to the new start position 
            // allocate memory:
            length = end_pos - start_pos;
            buffer = new char[length];

            // read data as a block: (end_pos - start_pos) blocks form read pointer 
            is.read(buffer, length);    
            is.close();    
            // print content:
            std::cout.write(buffer, length);    
            delete[] buffer;
            start_pos = end_pos; // update start pointer    
        }

        //wait and restart with new data 
        sleep(1);
        is.open(filePath, std::ifstream::binary);    
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

`